# Why is subclassing undesirable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

Why does the UIApplication class need a delegate to have "things" done on its behalf? Why can't this class do "things" directly without the need for an intermediate object such as a delegate? What is the purpose of that principle?

In the same way I ask myself: why isn't it possible to directly access the keyboard in order to dismiss it? Why is there a need for signaling the view controller as a delegate in order to resign first responder?

Comment: one question in the title another two in the post and they are not exactly related. consider dividing your post into 2-3 questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why not subclass UIApplication? Why use a delegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763658/why-not-subclass-uiapplication-why-use-a-delegate)

Answer (score 3):

Delegation is a core design pattern. It allows for the seperation of responsibilities between parts of your program. The idea is that the part of your program that, for example, draws to the screen probably shouldn't be talking to your database. There are several reasons for this:

1. Performance: if the same object that draws to the screen access your data store, you're going to run into performance problems. Period. Full stop.
2. Code maintanence: it's easier to conceptualize code that is properly modularized. (For me, anyway)
3. Flexibility: If you subclass in your code, that's great - until you start running into monolithic classes that have all sorts of undesired behavior. You'll reach the point where you have to overload behaviors to turn things off, and your property namespace can become polluted. Try categories, delegatation, and blocks for altrnatives. As king Solomon says in Ecclesiastes, paraphrased: There's a time and place for everything under the sun.

To make it easier to write, read, iterate upon, and maintain your program, it is strongly advised that you follow certain practices. You're welcome to subclass many classes, and Apple won't reject your app for poor code, provided that it runs as advertised. That said, if you don't abide by specific tried and true practices, you're digging your own grave. Sub passing isn't inherently bad, but categories, protocols, and blocks are so fascinating, that I'd prefer them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is subclassing undesirable?

Subclassing isn't undesirable. It's just that it's not always the right solution, and it's often better to use composition instead of inheritance. Lots has been written on this on Stack Overflow already, to the point that your title puts this question in danger of being closed as a duplicate. Rather than trying to repeat, I'll just point to one of the more popular questions covering this topic: [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/643383)

> Why does the UIApplication class need a delegate to have "things" done
>   on its behalf? Why can't this class do "things" directly without the
>   need for an intermediate object such as a delegate? What is the
>   purpose of that principle?

It provides a much looser coupling that allows Apple to change or replace the application object without breaking existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are very useful but they also have their place and time. It is also very possible to go about without using delegates. There are certain instances though, where delegates are important. For instance, when you use the uiTextview delegate, it is important for the controlling class to know when the text changes so it can handle it. And, because different classes may want to handle this event in different ways (limit characters, capitalize letters, etc) its easiest to use a delegate.

You may be saying: Yes, but why not just make a subclass with desired behavior? Well, this is possible, but there are a few reasons why you should not proceed this way. Firstly, you may override a behavior that is happening before the delegate is called. Next, it can be dangerous because you might accidentally override a function which was necessary. Third, it is a lot more work and more code, so it will be harder to debug. Imagine you have a form with 100 textboxes and they all have different behaviours. you would not want to create 100 subclasses... its much easier to do a switch case and delegate appropriately.